# CORS error with file: URL, what is the best approach?

Tags: node.js

So I want to have a node web app running on a shared network drive, and other computers be able to use the web app other than the machine running it. I run into the CORS cross-origin error when opening using file:/// because the web app needs access to some JSON files inside the same folder. Publicly hosting the web app is not an option.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}).listen(8888);
```

This code seems to only host for the local machine by ip, preferably I'd be able to use navigate to it by file path.

What is the best approach to this? I'm looking for something lightweight if possible. I have heard of Electron.js but is this the optimal approach?

Comment: How do you access a node app with file://?

Comment: I can access with localhost:8888/index.html and have no CORS error, but accessing by file://.../parent_folder/index.html would produce the error because of the cross-origin policy.

Comment: But that's not the node app. With file://.../parent_folder/index.html you are opening a HTML site in your browser. Your node app is not involved. Your node app is a application server listening on port 8888. You can't access the app with file://

Comment: Right. So ultimately, is it possible for index.html to read the .json files needed in any way, and the other computers could also access this site?

Comment: You could disable CORS in some browsers but it's not possible in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

File directly loaded in a browser will always be rejected because of CORS. You need to load file from web server, through HTTP protocol and CORS will not be problem. Just use a webserver as localhost, no need to go public. Simply put that file in root directory of the localhost and access it as http://localhost/yourfile.html  put other files there as well.